# How to return count only if count is greater than 0 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want the `count()` function query return value if count is greater than 0 in SQL Server.

I am using this query, but it returns created date-wise count. If I remove created column from group then it causes an error.

```
select count(*) as error_count 
from error_info 
group by created 
having count(*) > 0 
  and convert(datetime, created)  >= '2022-12-01 10:01:41.000' 
  and convert(datetime, created) < '2022-12-07 08:59:08.290'
```

As per my requirement, this query should return total records as count between given dates only if records exist in table. it should not return 0 count.

I want total records as count between given dates only if greater than 0.

Comment: Is the datetime column  created really text?, covert takes a lot of time

Comment: The `HAVING` is for aggregate clauses, the *`WHERE`* is not non-aggregate clauses. Also, why are you converting your `created` column to a `datetime`? Is it *not* a date and time data type already? if so, that is a fatal and fundamental flaw in your design that you really need to fix.

Comment: @nbk no created column is not text its datetime. i have to return as text that's why i have converted it.

Comment: Add table structure, data sample and expected results

Comment: @Rahul the system automatically converts your text string for comparison in datetime, so the convert is obsolete

Comment: Not that familiar with sql-server but I guess you can't have a HAVING without a group by and since you don't want a group by you should use where..

Comment: if i use where then i am not able to put condition like count(*) > 0.  actually i want total records count only if count is greater than 0.  i have to return total records count between given dates.

Comment: @Horaciux Thanks, its working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use filter in `where` clause not in `having`

```
  select error_count from (
    select count(*) as error_count 
    from error_info 
    where
     created  >= '2022-12-01 10:01:41.000' 
    and created < '2022-12-07 08:59:08.290') e
   where error_count>0
```

Comment: its giving date wise count. i want total count

Comment: add table structure, data sample and expected results

Comment: this will give you no rows when zero error counted

Comment: in this table, there are only 3 columns id (primary key), error details (varchar), created (datetime). this query is returning multiple rows like 1,1,1,3,1,1 in this way but i want total count in only one row.   and query should return count only if records exists in between given date.

Comment: I was about to post that exact same thing when the message popped up that this answer had an edit